# Странный баг во всех браузерах

Tags: windows, google-chrome, opera

Windows 10 pro x 64 переустанавливал раз 8
во всех браузерах (даже без синхронизации) не отрисовываются окна например:
в опере "скачаные файлы/VPN). Нажимаю, иконка отрисовывается, что нажато.
прозрачный интерфейс. т.е. наугад нажав примерно где файл, я могу запустить что то скачаное. В Google Chrome не отрисовываются такие элементы, как "Разрешить всплывающее окно / установить(удалить) расширение / Разрешить adobe flash / разрешить микро / разрешить уведомления / etc. Причем в хроме если вызывается, например, alert, то вообще вкладки не возможно закрыть, пока не прибить их диспетчером вкладок chrome и закрыть. (окно становится неактивным)

Даже на абсолютно свежей Win ничего не меняется, баги остаются. 
Даже без входа в акк (без сторонних расширений).
На linux вроде такого небыло бага

Что это вообще может быть? Вирусов нет.

Comment: Я полагаю драйвера и сопутствующий для комплектующих софт. Вообще под ваше железо именно для win10 x64 драйверы от производителя есть?

Comment: Есть, Samsung update все драйвера (кроме видят радеон) подтянул.

Comment: 99% вероятность того, что это именно драйвера на видеокарту.